# Deserialize boolean element with string attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to construct a class that would map with this XML structure, but can't figure out how. I've seen examples here where I can use [XmlText] if the element value is a string. In my case, the element value is boolean. How should I construct my "Service" class?

(I think) I know how to take care of the "Services" element :-). It's just an array of "Service" objects. I'm just not sure how to build the "Service" class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<MyConfigs>
    <Services>
        <Service Name="ServiceName">true</Service>
    </Services>
</MyConfigs>
```

I have this:

```
[XmlArray("Services")]
[XmlArrayItem("Service")]
public Service[] Services { get; set; }
```

And this:

```
public class Service
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // How do I get the boolean value here?????
}
```

Comment: What programming language are you working with? Can you post more of the XML tree?

Comment: I updated the post. I'm using C#. I have other elements in the XML tree, but I only need help constructing that particular boolean element with a string attribute. Thanks!

Comment: So you want to read the XML and initialize class instances based upon what XML nodes are encountered in a tree traversal?

Comment: Yes. I updated the post with more info on what I've got and what I'm stilling missing. Hope that helps clarify it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into using an out-of-the-box config file?  If you want a bit more structure, you can build out a [custom configuration section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[XmlText]
public bool ServiceValue {get;set;}
```

Comment: That works!!! Somehow I just presumed that [XmlText] is meant for string values only. Duh! Thanks so much for your help :).